# Is there a smaller set $S$ than $\mathbb Q$ that is dense in $\mathbb R$ ? And if such set exist does $S$ dense in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and then $\mathbb Q$ is countable (so it's a quite small set). But is there a smaller set $S$ than $\mathbb Q$ s.t. $S$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ ? And if yes, does such a set is dense in $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: Smaller in what sense? The only sets that are smaller (in the sense of cardinality) than countably infinite sets are finite sets, and certainly no finite set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But there are many many many proper subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are dense in $\mathbb{R}$: in fact, given any dense subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the set $D \setminus \{ a \}$ will also be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ for any $a \in D$, so that you can form infinite strictly descending chains $D_0 \supsetneq D_1 \supsetneq D_2 \supsetneq \cdots$ of dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In fact, if you pick a _random_ subset of $\mathbb Q$ by saying that each rational should be in your set with the same nonzero probability, independently, then the subset will _almost certainly_ be dense in $\mathbb R$ (and $\mathbb Q$).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can take for example the dyadic numbers $$\mathcal D=\left\{\frac{m}{2^n}\mid m\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N\right\}.$$
Since it's dense in $\mathbb R$ it's obviously dense in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Why is it "obviously dense in $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @John: Since you can approche any number $x\in\mathbb R$ by a sequence of $\mathcal D$, you can obviously approche any number of $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ by a sequence of $\mathcal D$.

Comment: Perhaps one intuitive way to see that it is "obvious" is to look at a 12 inch ruler marked in halves, quarter, eighths, sixteenths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes : remove one single point from $\mathbb Q$, this is still dense in $\mathbb R$.

To your second question it will obviously be dense in $\mathbb Q$ : any point in $\mathbb R$ can be approximated as close as we want, so of course this is the case for points in $\mathbb Q$ in particular !